Error Installing ChatterBot: "× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully" on Python 3.12.3
I'm trying to install the ChatterBot module using Python 3.12.3, but I keep encountering the following error:
× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.

Screenshot showing the error in detail: enter image description here
Steps I've Tried:
Using the pip download command: I tried running pip download --platform <platform> but it didn't resolve the issue.
I’ve tried various solutions from different sources, but none of them worked.

Chatterbot only works till python 3.8
https://pypi.org/project/ChatterBot/
You need to install python 3.8 separately to make it work.

Here is the image from ChatterBot:

